# How to get a simple layout with the vuetify Grid?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to make a simple layout where I have a row that occupies the minimum and the next row occupies 100% of the remaining space.

I would like to do it with the vuetify grid system

Actual
[image]
Expected
[image]

Could anyone help me to achieve the layout?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-container class="pa-0" fluid style="background-color: purple;">
    <v-row style="background-color: yellow;">
      <v-col cols=6 style="background-color: blue;">
        <v-card style="background-color: red;">small A</v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols=6>
        <v-card style="background-color: red;">small B</v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row style="background-color: yellow;">
      <v-col cols=12 style="background-color: green;">
        <v-card style="background-color: red;">big</v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/caeycae/pen/YzWyRrW

Comment: Going by the layout that you chose, You need to keep adding `height: 100%` until the parent element which is limited to occupy the entire layout. https://codepen.io/m4n0/pen/LYZGNwv Flexbox parent container so that it occupies the rest of the height.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container class="pa-0 fill-height" fluid style="background-color: purple;">
        <v-row style="background-color: yellow;">
          <v-col cols=6 style="background-color: blue;">
            <v-card style="background-color: red;">small A</v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols=6>
            <v-card style="background-color: red;">small B</v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row style="background-color: yellow;" class="fill-height">
          <v-col cols=12 style="background-color: green;">
            <v-card style="background-color: red;" class="fill-height">big</v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Add the class 'fill-height' to

- the first `v-container`
- the last `v-row` and its inner `v-card`